# How can I show images in edit form nested use dropzonejs and Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, dropzone.js

My problem lies with displaying the image in the edit nested form. How can it be done?

I have 2 models: Product and Photo.

model photo.rb

```
belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
```

model product.rb

```
has_many :photos, as: :photoable, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
```

products_controller :

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
def update
  respond_to do |format|
   if @product.update(product_params)
    format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Cập nhật thành công.!.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
   else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :category_id, photos_attributes: [:image, :photoable_id, :photoable_type, :position])
end
```

upload.js :

```
autoProcessQueue : false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 5,
maxFilesize: 1, 
acceptedMimeTypes: "image/*",
previewsContainer: "#previews",
paramName: "product[photos_attributes][][image]",
addRemoveLinks: true,
dictRemoveFile: "delete",
init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;
  this.element.querySelector("#submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
  });
  this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/products");
  });
},
```

Comment: Please provide links to questions that have helped you the most. Also, just by tagging urgent does not help the post's visibility.

Comment: @Hunter Stevens : thanks for your comments, i'll draw lessons for the next time :)